# What is the easiest way to earn 9999 coins

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

9999 coins is super tricky and maximum number getting this many coins allows you to buy outfits that cost 9999 skeleton and 3D 8 bit blocky version also this can help you participate endlessly in challenges. If you want to buy many outfits this is your number also do you want toad hints each is 50 get this many coins for endless ones.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get 9999 coins is to first collect all the invincible moons and coins then play balloon world playing balloon world helps you get a lot of coins by finding balloons.